# SSL/TLS handshake error after client key exchange

Tags: apache, ssl, client-certificates, handshake

I'm attempting to implement certificate-based authentication, and I'm getting an error during the SSL/TLS handshake. I've tried to debug it using `openssl s_client -state -debug -connect example.si:443`, but I'm honestly not versed enough to be able to interpret the output:

http://pastebin.com/7BiJXeAY

From what I can tell, the certificate chain is properly verified (which I've also checked [here](https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/#certChecker)), and it doesn't seem like I've made any mistakes in my `httpd.conf` file, when setting the VirtualHost on the Apache 2.2 server:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot D:/www/authentication
   ServerName lpt.uni-mb.si
   ServerAlias lpt.uni-mb.si
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\ssl\22_lpt.uni-mb.si.crt"
   SSLCACertificateFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\ssl\root.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\ssl\server.key"
   SSLCertificateChainFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\ssl\11_Intermediate.crt"
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
   SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4
   SSLVerifyClient require
   SSLVerifyDepth  10
   SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
   <Directory "D:/www/authentication">
       Options Indexes Includes
       AllowOverride All
       Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from all
       Options +FollowSymlinks
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Could it be that there's some issue with the client key exchange, considering the very short write operation?

Comment: Though it will not solve your problem, you should not allow the obsolete SSLv2/v3 flavors, but rather configure TLS only: `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3`.

Comment: When testing mutual auth with certificates using `s_client`, you need to specify the certificate and key. Also see the [`s_client` man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_client.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see from your pastebin link, you issued:

```
openssl s_client -state -debug
    -CAfile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache 2.2\conf\ssl\root.crt"
    -connect lpt.uni-mb.si:443
```

yet you did not provide a client certificate. Try adding openssl's `-cert` and `-key` params with a cert/key file.

Comment: By providing `-key server.key -cert lpt.uni-mb.si.pem -CAfile root.crt`, the error at the end of the file changes to `SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 write change cipher spec A`. Am I providing the wrong key, certificate and CA?

Comment: You are mixing up server and client certs: `22_lpt.uni-mb.si.crt` and `server.key` are the server's cert/key, and completely independent of the client cert/key. By configuring `SSLVerifyClient require`. you are expecting clients to present a certificate signed with your CA cert (`root.crt`). openssl will need just this to connect.

Comment: You were right. I had to download the client's .pfx, then extract the public certificate and private key, and provide those - then it worked. Oh, and another thing.. it seemed like one of Intermediate certificates in the chain was missing in the browser, so I had to manually add that; no idea why. Either way, it's working now.

Comment: Great you made it! BTW checking your server with [SSL labs server test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=lpt.uni-mb.si&hideResults=on) is quite helpful if you want to keep up with security.